# Is it possible to use Hirb in the Heroku Console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have an app deployed on Heroku. I can access the remote heroku console from my local computer via the command:

```
heroku console
```

I have the Hirb gem installed in my app by putting Hirb in my gemfile, I am able to but cannot get any of the Hirb formatting to show up.

In Heroku console, I can run:

```
Hirb.enable
```

and in return, get

```
=> true
```

But when I run `User.all` I don't get a table in return, just the old unformatted records. Is there anyway to get Hirb working on Heroku console?

Comment: add hirb in your Gemfile and try it :)

Comment: Tried that already, but doesn't work. The steps I did above were after installing the gem via the gemfile.

Comment: I have the same problem. it gives me `true` but no format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround described in a GitHub issue at 
https://github.com/cldwalker/hirb/issuesearch?state=closed&q=heroku#issue/37

Comment: Unfortunately, the workaround suggested there doesn't work either. I emailed Heroku and they said it's currently impossible to use Hirb on their console. In the future, they might be able to support it.

Comment: No. It worked for me yesterday. Note that there is a typo in the first answer. Skip to the last answer to see the correction.

Comment: Hi, I cannot access this github issue...but I am having difficulty with hirb on heroku....

Comment: here is a working link to the issue on github: https://github.com/cldwalker/hirb/issues/37